# How to seperate a column with comma delimited values into multiple rows SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pivot, ssms

Apologies in advance if this can't be done, I'm very inexperienced in SQL server.
I have a table like this:

| id | name | Pet | Pet_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | Dog, Dog, Cat | Cooper, Boot, Snowflake |
| 2 | Ben | Dog, Hamster, Cat | Cliff, Hammy, Tiger |

And I would like to pivot the last two columns, but keep the core columns, 'id' and 'name' the same so we end up with

| id | name | Pet | Pet_Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adam | Dog | Cooper |
| 1 | Adam | Dog | Boot |
| 1 | Adam | Cat | Snowflake |
| 2 | Ben | Dog | Cliff |
| 2 | Ben | Hamster | Hammy |
| 2 | Ben | Cat | Tiger |

I was considering creating a temp tables with Pet and Pet_Name and joining them and creating a new column 'name' in this temp table with the owner name, then joining this to the original table on 'name' - but this sounds very convoluted. Is there a cleaner way to do this perhaps?

Comment: Ideally part of your project should be to fix this design. Storing delimited values like this violates 1NF and is nothing short of horrible to work with. This should be two tables.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: "sounds" & "convoluted" & "very convoluted" & "cleaner" don't mean anything in particular & are not helpful. What exactly is the problem? What is you 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how you are stuck accomplishing what in what process? [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following solution.

It is using JSON and will work starting from SQL Server 2016 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, _Name VARCHAR(20), Pet VARCHAR(MAX), Pet_Name VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (_Name, Pet, Pet_Name) VALUES
('Adam', 'Dog, Dog, Cat', 'Cooper, Boot, Snowflake'),
('Ben', 'Dog, Hamster, Cat', 'Cliff, Hammy, Tiger');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

;WITH rs AS 
(
     SELECT ID, _Name
         , s = '["' + REPLACE(REPLACE(pet,SPACE(1),''), @separator, '","') + '"]'
         , s1 = '["' + REPLACE(REPLACE(Pet_Name,SPACE(1),''), @separator, '","') + '"]'
     FROM @tbl
 )
 SELECT ID, _Name, pet.[value] AS pet_name, pet_name.[value] AS pet_name
 FROM rs
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (s, N'$') AS pet
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (s1, N'$') AS pet_name
 WHERE pet.[key] = pet_name.[key];
```

**Output**

```
+----+-------+----------+-----------+
| ID | _Name | pet_name | pet_name  |
+----+-------+----------+-----------+
|  1 | Adam  | Dog      | Cooper    |
|  1 | Adam  | Dog      | Boot      |
|  1 | Adam  | Cat      | Snowflake |
|  2 | Ben   | Dog      | Cliff     |
|  2 | Ben   | Hamster  | Hammy     |
|  2 | Ben   | Cat      | Tiger     |
+----+-------+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

My friend, I hope this piece of code helps you to achieve what you want.

First of all, I prefer to have a Table-valued function to use in general not just in a query. This function returns a table with two columns `ItemIndex` and `ItemCharacter`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[StrigSplitFunction]( 
  @String varchar(max)
 ,@Separator varchar(10))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ItemIndex, value AS 
   ItemCharacter
   FROM STRING_SPLIT(@String, @Separator)
)
GO
```

Then I use this function in select query to generate what you want from your table:

```
SELECT T.Id
    , T.[Name]
    , A.ItemCharacter AS Pet
    , (SELECT B.ItemCharacter FROM [StrigSplitFunction] (T.Pet_Name,',') AS 
B WHERE B.ItemIndex = A.ItemIndex)  AS Pet_Name
FROM [TableName] AS T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM [StrigSplitFunction] (T.Pet,',')) as A
```

If you need any more description write for me in comment.

Comment: `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` Warning - logical nonsense. Your code only appears to work correctly but your ordering is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Table Data Input:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TempTbl') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TempTbl;
GO

CREATE TABLE #TempTbl
(
    ID INT NULL,
    Name VARCHAR(4000) NULL,
    Pet VARCHAR(4000) NULL,
    Pet_Name VARCHAR(4000) NULL
);

INSERT INTO #TempTbl
    (ID, Name, Pet, Pet_Name)
VALUES
    (1, 'Adam', 'Dog, Dog, Cat', 'Cooper, Boot, Snowflake'),
    (2, 'Ben', 'Dog, Hamster, Cat', 'Cliff, Hammy, Tiger');

--
SELECT * FROM #TempTbl;
```

Code to Split the String Respectively: **Works with any version of SQL2008 and above**

```
;WITH _CSV_Pet
AS (
       SELECT ID,
              Name,
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING((Pet + ','), 1, CHARINDEX(',', (Pet + ','), 1) - 1))) AS "val",
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING((Pet + ','), CHARINDEX(',', (Pet + ','), 1) + 1, LEN((Pet + ','))))) AS "rem"
       FROM #TempTbl
       UNION ALL
       SELECT a.ID,
              a.Name,
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(a.rem, 1, CHARINDEX(',', a.rem, 1) - 1))) AS "val",
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(a.rem, CHARINDEX(',', a.rem, 1) + 1, LEN(a.rem))))
       FROM _CSV_Pet AS a
       WHERE LEN(a.rem) >= 1
   ),
     _CSV_Pet_Name
AS (
       SELECT ID,
              Name,
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING((Pet_Name + ','), 1, CHARINDEX(',', (Pet_Name + ','), 1) - 1))) AS "val",
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING((Pet_Name + ','), CHARINDEX(',', (Pet_Name + ','), 1) + 1, LEN((Pet_Name + ','))))) AS "rem"
       FROM #TempTbl
       UNION ALL
       SELECT a.ID,
              a.Name,
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(a.rem, 1, CHARINDEX(',', a.rem, 1) - 1))) AS "val",
              LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(a.rem, CHARINDEX(',', a.rem, 1) + 1, LEN(a.rem))))
       FROM _CSV_Pet_Name AS a
       WHERE LEN(a.rem) >= 1
   )
SELECT CSV1.ID,
       CSV1.Name,
       CSV1.Value AS "Pet",
       CSV2.Value AS "Pet_Name"
FROM (
         SELECT CSV.ID,
                CSV.Name,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS "Idx",
                CSV.val AS "Value"
         FROM _CSV_Pet AS CSV
     ) AS CSV1
JOIN (
         SELECT CSV.ID,
                CSV.Name,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS "Idx",
                CSV.val AS "Value"
         FROM _CSV_Pet_Name AS CSV
     ) AS CSV2
    ON CSV2.ID = CSV1.ID AND CSV2.Idx = CSV1.Idx
ORDER BY CSV1.ID ASC
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: `ORDER BY (SELECT 0)` Warning - logical nonsense. Your code only appears to work correctly but your ordering is not guaranteed.

Comment: It works perfectly for any given range in any order. i had already tested it.
Even `ORDER BY (SELECT 1)` gives you the same result as `ORDER BY (SELECT 0)`